# AngularJS Directive which avoids rendering of images on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a AngularJS application  using Twitter Bootstrap with its Grid Layout.
What I like is to write a directive, which allows me to not only set `display:none` to images on mobile devices, but to avoid rendering them (to save bandwith and enhance speed on mobile devices). So I thought of something like a directive which checks for a element whether `display:none` is set. If so, the element (and all below) should be removed from the DOM. Sadly the image is already rendered at this moment.

How can I avoid that images get rendered on mobile devices? Is the directive to late? Is the dom already rendered by then?

Greets
Marc

Comment: AngularJS waits for DOMContentLoaded before parsing for directives. Images aren't loaded for DOMContentLoaded to be considered complete, but it sounds like you want AngularJS to remove DOM elements prior to this event which I don't believe is possible.

Note that if you're using @media queries via CSS, you will run into issues with desktop users resizing their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to write the directive for you, but you could start with the [ngSrc directive source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L86) and only set the attribute under certain conditions...  90% of it is comments and docs, there's just a little code at the bottom actually.  I think this is the basic link function for the directive, `normalized` is something like `ngSrc`, the same code is used for `ngHref`.

```
return {
  priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
      if (!value)
         return;

      attr.$set(attrName, value);

      // on IE, if "ng:src" directive declaration is used and "src" attribute doesn't exist
      // then calling element.setAttribute('src', 'foo') doesn't do anything, so we need
      // to set the property as well to achieve the desired effect.
      // we use attr[attrName] value since $set can sanitize the url.
      if (msie) element.prop(attrName, attr[attrName]);
    });
  }
```